# How best can I querySelectorAll inputs by their name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to populate an array with html input field names then further match them to json object names to I can assign values into them at once as below

*Kindly assist with a proper querySelectorAll(input) to get input fields by their name instead of their class names as the below is doing*

```
var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input'));
```

Then reuse in code below

```
Object.keys(recipient).map(function (dataItem) {
    inputs.map(function (inputItem) {
          return (inputItem.name === dataItem) ? (inputItem.value = recipient[dataItem]) : false;
    });
});
```

My data looks like so:

```
"data": {
        "type": "beneficiaries",
        "id": "C9QV9ZNZ",
        "attributes": {
            "bank_name": null,
            "last_name": "xcxc",
            "beneficiary_type": "MT",
            "mobile_money_msisdn": null,
            "branch_name": null,
            "recipient_type": "P",
            "first_name": "dfgdf",
            "middle_name": null,
            "name": "dfgdf xcxc",
            "mobile": null,
            "account_number": "111111111"
        }
```

Comment: Why not `document.getElementsByClassName()`?

Comment: I actually need to automate because there is just a lot of fields in multiple pages, some have more fields and some have less

Comment: Unclear what you actually need. Can you give like sample HTML and JSON? Not sure why you are using map for a loop.

Comment: So you have an object that has `{ name1: 123, name2: 345, name3, 678 }` and you want to put the value into input with same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nested loops is overkill. Just loop over the inputs and see if the key exists in the object.

```js
var data = {
  name1: 123,
  name2: 345,
  name3: 678
}

document.querySelectorAll("input[name]").forEach( function (input) {
  var name = input.name;
  if (data[name]) input.value = data[name]
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="name1" />
  <input name="name2" />
  <input name="name3" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @epascarello, though will still need to loop and jump to the inner object within data